# Null reference exceptions on properties of a newly instantiated class? What's going on here?

Tags: vb.net

I'm toying around with a 3rd party library and something has me absolutely puzzled.

When I instantiate this class, immediately all of the properties of the class throw exceptions before any more code even runs.  Why is this happening?  It's not just this `TypedSegmentPWK` class, it's all of the typedsegment classes.. of which there are many.

[image]

Simple instantiation fails

```
Imports OopFactory.X12.Parsing
Imports OopFactory.X12.Parsing.Model
Imports OopFactory.X12.Parsing.Model.Typed

....

Dim test As New TypedSegmentPWK
test.PWK04_EntityIdentifierCode = "blah"
```

Assigning a value to PWK04_EntityIdentifierCode or any other property of `test` fails with a null reference exception.

TypedSegmentPWK:

```
Namespace OopFactory.X12.Parsing.Model.Typed
Public Class TypedSegmentPWK
    Inherits TypedSegment

    Public Sub New()

    Public Property PWK01_ReportTypeCode As String
    Public Property PWK02_ReportTransmissionCode As String
    Public Property PWK03_ReportCopiesNeeded As Integer?
    Public Property PWK04_EntityIdentiferCodeEnum As EntityIdentifierCode
    Public Property PWK04_EntityIdentifierCode As String
    Public Property PWK05_IdentificationCodeQualifier As String
    Public Property PWK05_IdentificationCodeQualifierEnum As IdentificationCodeQualifier
    Public Property PWK06_IdentificationCode As String
    Public Property PWK07_Description As String
    Public Property PWK08_ActionsIndicated As String
    Public Property PWK09_RequestCategoryCode As String
End Class
```

End Namespace

TypedSegment:

```
Namespace OopFactory.X12.Parsing.Model
Public MustInherit Class TypedSegment
    Protected Sub New(segmentId As String)

    Public Event Initialized As EventHandler
    Public Event Initializing As EventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub OnInitialized(e As EventArgs)
    Protected Overridable Sub OnInitializing(e As EventArgs)
End Class
```

End Namespace

Full source here: https://github.com/KeyMarkInc/OopFactory.X12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the properties reference `_segment` defined in `TypedSegment`, e.g.

```cs
public string PWK04_EntityIdentifierCode
{
    get { return _segment.GetElement(4); }
    set { _segment.SetElement(4, value); }
}
```

However, the `_segment` variable is not initialized until `TypedSegment.Initialize(Container parent, X12DelimiterSet delimiters)` is called...

```cs
internal void Initialize(Container parent, X12DelimiterSet delimiters)
{
    OnInitializing(new EventArgs());
    _segment = new Segment(parent, delimiters, _segmentId);
    OnInitialized(new EventArgs());
}
```

This is an internal method, so presumably something in this framework is supposed to call it, and not you as the user.  So, I would guess the answer is that you are using the `TypedSegmentPWK` class incorrectly, although I don't know what the correct way is.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah that's probably the case.  It's for healthcare EDI which I don't know very well, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if I'm using it incorrectly.  I appreciate it

Comment: @user1003916 The unit tests may give you some clue about how to use the library.  If you have some data (XML?), maybe start with `X12Parser.ParseMultiple(string)` and see what that gives you.  Good luck! :-)